# Changing Itemsource at runtime MVVM

Tags: wpf

I'd like to dynamically change the Item source of a datagrid depending on what the user selects. For example my users will ftp different xml files from a server, each contains slightly different information. I have models of the different objects which my view models stores as different generic lists...depending on the object. In my view I have one datagird which I would like to bind to one of the generic lists my vm depending on the file the user choose to ftp. How to I dynamically change the ItemSource biding of my datagrid?  Any ideas?

I would like to keep code out of the code behind if possible.

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to have a DataGrid with AutoGenerateColumns true and simply change the itemssource

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" AutoGenerateColumns=true/>
```

viewmodel

```
  public IList<object> MyData {get;set;} //<- INotifyPropertyChanged should be implemented
```

that should work but i would not go this way ;)

i would do it with datatemplates and specific and not generic "wrapper" objects for your different lists.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will try data templates, but I was able to display the different lists in the interim using ICollectionView and setting the list to it's default view like this: ICollectionView DGItemsSourceBinding { get; set{ _DGItemSourceBiding = value; RaisePropetyChange("DGItemsSourceBinding);}}                DGItemsSourceBinding = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListTheUserChoose);